# Terraform - Reference for_each from a module output

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use Terraform to create multiple storage containers, and then upload multiple blobs to each container.

I have the part of creating multiple containers working, but can't figure out how to reference the for_each output of each container when uploading the blobs.

**Storage Container Module** (Works)

```
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "azure" {
  for_each              = toset(var.storage_containers)
  name                  = each.value
  storage_account_name  = var.storage_account_name
  container_access_type = var.storage_account_container_access_type
}

output "azurerm_storage_container_name" {
  value = toset(keys(azurerm_storage_container.azure))
}
```

**Child Module** (Works)

```
module "storage_container" {
  source = "C:/TerraformModules/modules/azurerm/azurerm_storage_container"
  storage_account_name = module.storage_account.azurerm_storage_account_name
  storage_containers   = var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAMES
  tags                 = var.TAGS
}
```

**Code to upload blob** (doesn't work for trying to upload into each container)

```
**In a variables.tf file**
variable "STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS" {
  description = "The default blobs in each storage container"
  type        = list(string)
}

**In a vars.auto.tfvars file**
STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS = ["one", "two", "three"]

**In a main.tf file**
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob" {
  for_each               = toset(var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS)
  name                   = each.value
  storage_account_name   = module.storage_account.azurerm_storage_account_name
  storage_container_name = module.storage_container[each.value].azurerm_storage_container_name
  type                   = "Block"
  source_content         = "blob file"
}
```

If I were to set the container name in `storage_container_name`, it works and the container gets each blob. But I'm not able to reference the container from the module.

I have this error:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on storage_blobs.tf line 5, in resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob":
   5:   storage_container_name = module.storage_container[each.value].azurerm_storage_container_name
    |----------------
    | each.value is "two"
    | module.storage_container is object with 1 attribute "azurerm_storage_container_name"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

What I need to achieve:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob" {
  for_each               = toset(var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS)
  name                   = each.value
  storage_account_name   = module.storage_account.azurerm_storage_account_name
  storage_container_name = # How to reference the storage accounts created with the `storage_container ` module? #
  type                   = "Block"
  source_content         = "blob file"
}
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS` and `var.storage_containers`? These should be same?

Comment: No. So the var.storage_containers Are the containers I create. And STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS is a list of blobs I want to create. So I just need a way of referencing the containers from the storage_container module in the azurerm_storage_blob resource.

Comment: How do you match `STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS` with `var.storage_containers`? There must be some relationship so that value in the first variable corresponds to the second one? Can you show example of `var.storage_containers`, and how it should match `STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS`?

Comment: So there is no relationship. `var.storage_containers` used in the `storage_container` module is referenced by `var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAMES`. That module just creates multiple storage accounts for me.

And `var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS` is in a separate resource that I use to create multiple blobs in the storage accounts.

I can't see how there needs to be a relationship between `var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS` and `var.storage_containers`.

I need a way to reference these storage accounts from the `storage_container` module, in the `azurerm_storage_blob` resource.

Comment: I've added "What I need to achieve:" to my post as an example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[storage_container_name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob#storage_container_name) takes only one value, not a list of values. So if you have 3 `STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS` and n number of `var.storage_containers` you have to iterate `n*3` times in `azurerm_storage_blob`.

Thus, you can try the following with [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setproduct.html):

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob" {

  for_each               = {for idx, val in setproduct(module.storage_container.azurerm_storage_container_name, var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS): idx=>val}

  name                   = each.value[1]
  storage_account_name   = module.storage_account.azurerm_storage_account_name
  storage_container_name = each.value[0]
  type                   = "Block"
  source_content         = "blob file"
}
```

Comment: Ok, that gives me an error:

Error: Invalid object key

  on storage_blobs.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob":
  11:   for_each               = {for idx, val in setproduct(module.storage_container.azurerm_storage_container_name, var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS): idx=>val}

The key expression produced an invalid result: string required

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Yes it can be done with setproduct. It works as `for_each               = {for idx, val in setproduct(var.STORAGE_CONTAINERS, var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS): idx=>val}`, I already use the `var.STORAGE_CONTAINERS` in the same project so I'll just re-use that.

Comment: Cool, I got it working with `for_each               = {for idx, val in setproduct(module.storage_container.azurerm_storage_container_name, var.STORAGE_CONTAINER_DEFAULT_BLOBS): idx=>val}` by changing the module output value to `value = [for name in azurerm_storage_container.azure:name.name]`